# Regex-based custom template filter doesn't find the first targeted word in a string (Django 2.1)

Tags: python, regex, django

I have a regex-based custom template filter that finds and highlights the keyword put into the search engine, like Google. For example, if the user searches "cake", my filter will highlight "cake" in "I just ate a cake."
Here is the code for the filter:

```
@register.filter(needs_autoescape=True)
@stringfilter
def highlight(value, search_term, autoescape=True):
    # first compile the regex pattern using the search_term
    pattern = re.compile(re.escape(search_term), re.IGNORECASE)
    # now replace
    new_value = pattern.sub('<span class="highlight">\g<0></span>', value)
    return mark_safe(new_value)
```

Code for search engine in views.py:

```
def query_search(request):
    articles = cross_currents.objects.all()
    search_term = ''
    if 'keyword' in request.GET:
        search_term = request.GET['keyword']
        articles = articles.annotate(similarity=Greatest(TrigramSimilarity('Title', search_term), TrigramSimilarity('Content', search_term))).filter(similarity__gte=0.03).order_by('-similarity')
    context = {'articles': articles, 'search_term': search_term}
    return render(request, 'query_search.html', context)
```

HTML template:

```
 <ul>
{% for article in articles %}
<li><a href="{% url 'search:article_detail' article.ArticleID %}">{{ article|highlight:search_term }}</a></li>
<p> {{ article.Content|highlight:search_term|show_excerpt:search_term }} </p>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The problem is that the filter doesn't highlight the first keyword that occurs but does it to all other keywords. For example, if the keyword is "cake" and a sentence is "my cake is a cake from a cake shop", it would only highlight the second and third "cake" but not the first one. Any idea why this is the case?

EDIT: here is code for `show_excerpt` filter (displays text surrounding the keyword in search results, like on Google):

```
@register.filter(needs_autoescape=True)
@stringfilter
def show_excerpt(value, search_term, autoescape=True):
    #make data into string and lower#
    original_text = str(value)
    lower_original_text = original_text.lower()
    #make keyword into string and lower#
    keyword_string = str(search_term)
    lower_keyword_string = keyword_string.lower()
    #find the position of the keyword in the data#
    keyword_index = lower_original_text.find(lower_keyword_string)
    #Specify the beginning and ending positions of the excerpt#
    start_index = keyword_index 
    end_index = keyword_index + 3000
    #Define the position range of excerpt#
    excerpt = original_text[start_index:end_index]
    return mark_safe(excerpt)
```

Comment: I don't find any issue with the `highlight` filter, show the `show_excerpt` filter's code

Comment: @AvinashRaj added =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't find any problem with your `highlight` filter but the problem may be because of `show_excerpt` filter. From your previous question, it clearly shows that you want to fetch only 300 chars exists before and after the search keyword and highlight only the search term.

```
# modified show_excerpt to get the surrounded chars
@register.filter(needs_autoescape=True)
@stringfilter
def show_excerpt(value, search_term, autoescape=True):
    match = re.search('.{0,300}' + re.escape(search_term) + '.{0,300}', str(value), re.IGNORECASE)
    if match: return mark_safe(match.group())
    return ''
```

Note that `.{0,300}` part of regex will match atleast 0 char and atmost 300 chars.

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks a lot! I didn't think the problem was with my other filter